# Convert MS Access data query into SQL Server database query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I found a MS Access `select` query and in where clause I found some issue to understand

I want to convert into a SQL Server query please help.

```
(((TABLE1.COL1) > #12/31/2011#) AND 
((TABLE2.LstUpdate) = DateValue(DFirst("RDate", "TABEL3"))))
```

I want to convert this MS Access select query into an equivalent T-SQL query

Comment: Can you update with the whole query? Also, for sql change the # for ' in dates as that's an access only thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T-SQL equivalent for `#12/31/2011#` will be `'20111231'`.

T-SQL equivalent of `DFirst("RDate","TABEL3")` will be `select top 1 RDate from TABEL3`

`DateValue` is function converting string to datetime, if your `RDate` type is `date` or `datetime` then you don't need that conversion, if `RDate` is `varchar` or other string type - you can use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function.